# Accessing Return Values from Oracle Text using Oracle Enhanced Adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, text

I am building a Rails application. The application uses MySql as the main database and the oracle-enhanced adapter to access a legacy Oracle database that contains documents the application needs to search. With the oracle-enhanced adapter, I want to use the existing Oracle Text index to search for documents. My Rails application can connect to the Oracle db and the scaffolding attached to my model is working fine.

What I need now what exactly is returned from oracle-enhanced adapter when it searches an Oracle Text index? Additionally, I need to know how to access the returned values. For example,  when I search the Oracle Index using the oracle-enhanced adapter syntax " Post.contains(:title, 'word')" does the returned information include document id, 
document name, document date, words found in the search, and any type 
document ranking or document score? I need any and all that information to update a results table in my MySql database. Can someone point me to where I 
can get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided in oracle_enhanced discussion group
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/oracle-enhanced/6Y52ihs9wtQ/discussion

Comment: Thank you for your patiences and guidance.